# Renderscript multidimensional array

Tags: android, arrays, multidimensional-array, renderscript

Is there a possibility to use two dimensional arrays in RenderScript for Android? Allocation only allows me to put a vector (1 dimensional) array into the allocation. But I have no idea how to generate two dimensional arrays. I [found a google groups discussion on this topic](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-developers/aLq4BGXYe5w), but this guy didn't received any answer. If I want to create a two dimensional array in the rs File, I get an error:

```
int array[10][10];
```

The following error will be displayed:

```
error: multidimensional arrays cannot be exported: 'array'
```

As I have seen in the renderscript files is that the arrays 2x2, 3x3 and 4x4 are based on one dimensional arrays. For me this is very restrictive to use. Because for math stuff there should be a support for calculation of big matrices too.

Answer (score 2):

Mark is static.  The issue is there is no clean way to export this to the Java reflected files.  There should be no issues with non-exported arrays.

RS does additional checked on globals which are not marked static.  As a general rule, if you are not setting them from the other side, make them static.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Actually I want to put data from Java to RenderScript an vice versa. With Allocations I figured out only to put a one dimensional array into an allocation. But I couldn't find out how to put two or three one dimensional arrays into an allocation. This would be help me to bring my data to RenderScript. Any idea how I can do this?

Comment: Just in case you do not get a better answer, you can always flatten 2D and 3D arrays to 1D array. It is extra hassle, but not sure there is any other way.